# HTML5 content for iPad

Tags: ipad, html, safari, mobile-safari, html5-video

As Flash content is not supported on iPad, we keep on hearing that the content can be converted into HTML5 content which works on the iPad.

So my question is specifically which are those formats that the iPad actually plays (like .swf is for Flash) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reiterating what @James-Santiago said, MP4 is the way to go and for converting, I'd recommend [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/).

Once you have your video decoded, add the HTML5 DOCTYPE and then the following code to play your video:

```
<video src="myVideo.mp4" controls></video>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various video codecs such as H.264 that HTML 5 developed video players can play.

You can read more into the concepts here: [Video - Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html)

There are several video encoders [out there](http://www.h264encoder.com/) that can convert your video into one of these formats usually with the mp4 extension.